# How to disable thanos sidecar in kube-prometheus-stack?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, sidecar, kube-prometheus-stack, thanos

As there are different thanos config in [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) templates and [values](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml), I want to understand what all it required to disable thanos sidecar?

Comment: I was working with this helm chart recently, and I was able to disable the sidecar by commenting out or simply deleting the thanos config block (**thanos: {}**) on line 3830 in the values file -> https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml

Comment: @helpinghand Thanks! Is it not required to remove `thanosService`, `thanosRuler` and multiple `thanos***` values?

Comment: I actually didn't need to do that and the sidecar was disabled.
But you can.

Comment: @helpinghand Thanks! It worked! You can post it as an answer, I will accept. Deleting `thanos: {}` does work for me, I have to comment configs inside `thanos` and set it default like `thanos: {}`.

Comment: Awesome. Good to know it worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working with this helm chart recently, and I was able to disable the sidecar by commenting out or simply deleting the thanos config block (**thanos: {}**) on line 3830 in the values file - https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml